# Why can't I transform tundra?

Tags: freeciv

I'm playing freeciv 2.5 with ruleset civ2civ3. I've Engineer on Tundra tile, and want to transform it into Plains, but cannot: proper action is in the menu, but is grayed out. Why? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

It's linux version, under Ubuntu 14.04. Tried under gtk2 and sdl client, the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found the answer in the docs. *Fusion Power* technology must be known to make such transformation possible.

Comment: Where is this documented?